# How to plot a maths function as a heatmap

Tags: r, plot

If x and y can vary from 0 to 10, how can I plot a maths function z = x*(y^2) as an image plot or heatmap ? The x and y should come to their respective axes and z value should be shown as colour on the plot. I could find method to plot only discrete values, not a continuous function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: see the ggplot2 package, specifically the geom_tile, setting your fill variable to z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
library(emdbook)
curve3d(x*y^2,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,10),sys3d="image")
```

`curve3d` is just a wrapper (the `sys3d` argument gives you a range of plotting possibilities) -- more generally, you can create a function and use `outer()` (if it's vectorized) to create a matrix, e.g.

```
xvec <- yvec <- seq(0,10,length.out=41)
z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) x*y^2)
image(xvec,yvec,z)
```

[image]