# Plotting math function with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following code plots a math function as a heatmap (from: [How to plot a maths function as a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738391/how-to-plot-a-maths-function-as-a-heatmap)):

```
xvec <- yvec <- seq(0,10,length.out=41)
z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) x*y^2)
image(xvec,yvec,z)
```

How can I create this using ggplot2 geom_tile() ?

Following commands do not work:

```
ggplot()+geom_tile(aes(x=xvec, y=yvec, z=z))
```

and

```
zdf = data.frame(z)
ggplot(zdf)+geom_tile(aes(z=zdf))
```

I am surprised not to find similar question on searching.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to arrange the X/Y coordinates and the data (`z` in your case) into a `data.frame` instead of a matrix.

For example:

```
xvec <- yvec <- seq(0,10,length.out=41)
df <- expand.grid(xvec, yvec)
df$z <- apply(df, 1, function(p) p[1] * p[2]^2)

head(df)

#   Var1 Var2 z
# 1 0.00    0 0
# 2 0.25    0 0
# 3 0.50    0 0
# 4 0.75    0 0
# 5 1.00    0 0
# 6 1.25    0 0

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + geom_tile(aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=z))
```

And you get:

[image]

Comment: expand.grid function is the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could also reshape your `outer` results with

```
xvec <- yvec <- seq(0,10,length.out=41)
z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) x*y^2)

ggplot(data.frame(xvec=xvec[row(z)], yvec=yvec[col(z)], z=as.numeric(z))) + 
    geom_tile(aes(x=xvec, y=yvec, fill=z))
```

What we are doing here is building a new data.frame with triplets of values to plot: (x,y,color). The problem is we have `length(xvec)` rows and `length(yvec)` columns but `length(xvec) * length(yvec)` actual observations. So this trick will repeat the row and column values to make them the same length as the `z` values. Since `z` is a matrix, `row(z)` will give the row number for each value in `z`. We use this to repeat the `xvec` values multiple times and keep them insync with the `z` values. Same goes for the `yvec` values but we match those up to the `columns` of `z`. This is another way to create a data.frame in the form

```
  xvec yvec z
1 0.00    0 0
2 0.25    0 0
3 0.50    0 0
4 0.75    0 0
5 1.00    0 0
6 1.25    0 0
```

Comment: It works but change in data is difficult to understand.

Comment: I tried to add some further explanation. But if your data isn't already in a matrix, then the `expand.grid` option probably would be best for you.